# Does Nyxbloom Ancient replace the entire mana ability or just the part that produces mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Nyxbloom Ancient](https://scryfall.com/card/thb/190/nyxbloom-ancient) has the following replacement effect:

> If you tap a permanent for mana, it produces three times as much of that mana instead.

I'm wondering whether the replacement effect ("instead") applies to the entire mana ability or just to the part that produces the mana. For example consider [Empowered Autogenerator](https://scryfall.com/card/c19/54/empowered-autogenerator):

> {T}: Put a charge counter on Empowered Autogenerator. Add X mana of any one color, where X is the number of charge counters on Empowered Autogenerator.

With Nyxbloom Ancient on the battlefield, do I get to place the charge counter on Empowered Autogenerator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Nyxbloom Ancient only modifies the mana produced. Empowered Autogenerator still gets a counter.**

[Rule 106.12b](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Mana) says

> A replacement effect that applies if a permanent “is tapped for mana” or tapped for mana of a specific type and/or amount **modifies the mana production event** while such an ability is resolving and producing mana or the specified type and/or amount of mana.

Empowered Autogenerator's activated ability has two separate instructions: first you add a counter, then you add mana. Only the second part is the mana production event, so only that part gets modified by Nyxbloom Ancient's ability.

Answer (score 4):

Nyxbloom Ancient replaces only the quantity of mana generated, and nothing else. You'll still only be able to cast Eldrazi spells off of Eldrazi Temple, and you'll still take damage from your Sulfurous Springs. So, yes, you will still be able to place a counter on your Autogenerator.

The [release notes for *Theros Beyond Death*](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/theros-beyond-death-release-notes-2020-01-10) state:

> Nyxbloom Ancient doesn't produce any mana itself. Rather, it causes permanents you tap for mana to produce more mana. If the mana ability of that permanent puts any restrictions or riders on the mana it produces, that will apply to all the mana it produces this way.

---

Some additional support from the rules:

> 614.1a Effects that use the word “instead” are replacement effects. Most replacement effects use the word “instead” to indicate what events will be replaced with other events.

Nyxbloom Ancient says "it produces three times as much of that mana instead". This indicates that only the quantity of mana produced is being replaced.

> 614.11b If an effect would have a player both draw a card and perform an additional action on that card, and the draw is replaced, the additional action is not performed on any cards that are drawn as a result of that replacement effect.

This rule specifically calls out that replacing a card draw + rider with an effect also overrules the rider. There is no similar rule for mana abilities, which implies that the riders still take effect.

Comment: Your quote from the THB release notes is also just one of the rulings on the card on Gatherer. And that ruling is not directly applicable here. This question isn't talking about a rider on the mana produced. It's talking about a completely separate action taken during the resolution of the mana ability.

Comment: In addition, rule 614.11b is specifically about replacing a card draw, and actions that would be taken on the card that is drawn. You can't generalize that to be relevant to any action taken along with another action that is replaced.

Comment: The ruling tells you how replacement effects work; that they replace only the specific portion of the effect that they call out. And I already acknowledged that 11b only applies to card draws, but my point is that there's a special rule for this case (to override the general "it only replaces the portion it replaces" concept) and since there is _not_ a special rule for mana abilities we can continue to understand that only the quantity is replaced. If you believe my conclusion is incorrect, that's fine, but I'd appreciate pointers to rules that contradict what I've said.

Comment: The issue here, as I see it, is that to "tap [a permanent] for mana" refers to the entire act of activating (and resolving) the mana ability, so it's unclear what part of that gets modified by an ability like on Nyxbloom Ancient. In other words, it's not clear what portion is getting replaced, so proving that "it only replaces the portion it replaces" doesn't resolve the problem. I've written my own answer with what I think is a better justification. And to be clear, I didn't disagree with your conclusion, just your reasoning.

Comment: @BenP. The question is whether "instead" refers to the entire mana ability or just the mana production event. I think the situation described by 614.11b is substantially different, so it cannot support any argument regarding the situation in question. Even more so since a dedicated rule (106.12b) exists that describes exactly this situation.